# How to implement GStreamer tee in C code

Tags: gstreamer

I have the following working pipeline. It has been tested using both command-line tool **gst-launch-1.0** and function `gst_parse_launch()`, and works in both cases.

```
videotestsrc  ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! videocrop left=80 right=80 ! tee name=t ! queue ! glupload ! glimagesink t. ! queue ! jpegenc ! avimux ! filesink location=output.avi
```

I've tried to set it up manually in code, but I'm now stuck on the following error (the application opens, but no video is displayed):

> Error received from element videotestsrc0 : Internal data flow error.
>
> Debugging information: gstbasesrc.c(2948): gst_base_src_loop ():
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoTestSrc:videotestsrc0: streaming task
>   paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)

I'm using GStreamer in a Qt application and the glimagesink links the video to a QML type. All code related to GStreamer is located in a GStreamer class called GStreamer. The entire cpp file is posted below, in case the issue is located somewhere I wouldn't guess. I apologize for non-relevant code.

```
static gboolean busCallback(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *message, gpointer data);

GStreamer::GStreamer(QQuickItem *parent) : QQuickItem(parent)
{
    qDebug() << "Constructed GSteamer";        
}    

void GStreamer::createPipeline()
{
    qDebug() << "Creating pipeline";      

    if(m_source.isEmpty()){
        qDebug() << "Error: Missing source property for GStreamer component";
        return;
    }

    if(m_videoItem.isEmpty()){
        qDebug() << "Error: Missing videoItem property for GStreamer component";
        return;
    }

    m_pipeline = gst_pipeline_new(NULL);
    m_sink = NULL;

    QByteArray ba = m_source.toLatin1();
    m_src = gst_element_factory_make(ba.data(), NULL);
    g_assert(m_src);


    m_filter = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "filter");
    g_assert(m_filter);

    g_object_set(G_OBJECT (m_filter), "caps", gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw", 
        "width", G_TYPE_INT, 640,
        "height", G_TYPE_INT, 480,
        NULL), 
    NULL);

    m_convert = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", NULL);
    g_assert(m_convert);

    m_crop = gst_element_factory_make("videocrop", "crop");
    g_assert(m_crop);

    g_object_set(G_OBJECT (m_crop), "left", 80, "right", 80, NULL);

    // Tee
    m_tee = gst_element_factory_make("tee", "videotee");
    g_assert(m_tee);

    // Display queue
    m_displayQueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "displayQueue");
    g_assert(m_displayQueue);    

    m_upload = gst_element_factory_make("glupload", NULL);
    g_assert(m_upload);    

    m_sink = gst_element_factory_make("qmlglsink", NULL);
    g_assert(m_sink);

    // Record queue
    m_recordQueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "recordQueue");
    g_assert(m_recordQueue);

    m_encode = gst_element_factory_make("jpegenc", NULL);
    g_assert(m_encode);

    m_mux = gst_element_factory_make("avimux", NULL);
    g_assert(m_mux);

    m_filesink = gst_element_factory_make("filesink", NULL);
    g_assert(m_filesink);

    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(m_filesink), "location", "output.avi", NULL);    

    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN (m_pipeline), m_src, m_filter, m_convert, m_crop, m_upload, m_sink, NULL);
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(m_pipeline), m_tee, m_displayQueue, m_recordQueue, m_encode, m_mux, m_filesink, NULL);

    // If I only link this simple pipeline, it works fine
    /*
   if(!gst_element_link_many(m_src, m_filter, m_convert, m_crop, m_upload, m_sink, NULL)){
        qDebug() << "Unable to link source";
    }
    */

    if(!gst_element_link_many(m_src, m_filter, m_convert, m_crop, m_tee, NULL)){
        qDebug() << "Unable to link source";
    }
    if(!gst_element_link_many(m_displayQueue, m_upload, m_sink, NULL)){
        qDebug() << "Unable to link display queue";
    }
    if(!gst_element_link_many(m_recordQueue, m_encode, m_mux, m_filesink, NULL)){
        qDebug() << "Unable to link record queue";
    }    

    GstPad *teeDisplayPad = gst_element_get_request_pad(m_tee, "src_%u");
    GstPad *queueDisplayPad = gst_element_get_static_pad(m_displayQueue, "sink");

    GstPad *teeRecordPad = gst_element_get_request_pad(m_tee, "src_%u");
    GstPad *queueRecordPad = gst_element_get_static_pad(m_recordQueue, "sink");

    if(gst_pad_link(teeDisplayPad, queueDisplayPad) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK){
        qDebug() << "Unable to link display tee";
    }

    if(gst_pad_link(teeRecordPad, queueRecordPad) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK){
        qDebug() << "Unable to link record tee";
    }

    //gst_object_unref(teeDisplayPad);
    gst_object_unref(queueDisplayPad);
    //gst_object_unref(teeRecordPad);
    gst_object_unref(queueRecordPad);    

    QQuickItem *videoItem = window()->findChild<QQuickItem *> (m_videoItem);
    g_object_set(m_sink, "widget", videoItem, NULL);

    // This will call gst_element_set_state(m_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING) when the window is ready
    window()->scheduleRenderJob (new SetPlaying (m_pipeline), QQuickWindow::BeforeSynchronizingStage);    

    m_bus = gst_element_get_bus(m_pipeline);

    gst_bus_add_watch(m_bus, busCallback, m_loop);
    gst_object_unref(m_bus);

    m_loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, false);
    g_main_loop_run(m_loop);     
}

static gboolean busCallback(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *message, gpointer data){
    qDebug() << "Callback function reached";
    switch(GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(message)){
        case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
            GError *error;
            gchar *debugInfo;
            gst_message_parse_error(message, &error, &debugInfo);
            qDebug() << "Error received from element" << GST_OBJECT_NAME(message->src) << ":" << error->message;
            qDebug() << "Debugging information:" << (debugInfo ? debugInfo : "none");
            //g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (m_message->src), error->message);
            //g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debugInfo ? debugInfo : "none");
            g_clear_error (&error);
            g_free (debugInfo);

            g_main_loop_quit(static_cast<GMainLoop *>(data));
            break;
        case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
            qDebug() << "End-Of-Stream reached.";
            g_main_loop_quit(static_cast<GMainLoop *>(data)); 
            break;
        default:
            qDebug() << "Unexpected message received."; 
            break;
        }
    return true;    
}

/**
The rest of the code is probably not relevant. It contains 
only destructor and some getters and setters.
**/

GStreamer::~GStreamer()
{
    gst_object_unref(m_bus);
    gst_element_set_state(m_pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(m_pipeline);
}

QString GStreamer::source() const
{
    return m_source;
}

void GStreamer::setSource(const QString &source)
{
    if(source != m_source){
        m_source = source;
    }
}

QString GStreamer::videoItem() const
{
    return m_videoItem;
}

void GStreamer::setVideoItem(const QString &videoItem)
{
    if(videoItem != m_videoItem){
        m_videoItem = videoItem;
    }
}
```

All member variables are defined in the .h file.

If I don't add tee element to the bin and links it in the pipeline, then the video shows up on the screen as expected. So I guess I'm messing up the pads on the tee element.

I've been following the tutorials in GStreamers documentation, so I don't understand why it's not working.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the difference between the the gst-launch line provided and the application code is the use of the `qmlglsink` element in the place of `glimagesink`.

The problem is that `qmlglsink` only accepts RGBA formatted video buffers however the `jpegenc` in the other branch of the `tee` does not accept RGBA formatted video buffers.  This leads to a negotiation problem as there is not common format supported by both branches of the `tee`.

The fix is to add a `videoconvert` element before `jpegenc` or a `glcolorconvert` element before `qmlglsink` so that both branches of the `tee` can negotiate to the same video format.

Side note: `glimagesink` contains a `glupload ! glcolorconvert ! actual-sink` internally so is converting video formats already.

Comment: Thank you!!!! I've been struggling with this for days, and this solved it.